# How to 2-way bind props with local data of a component in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, two-way-binding, vue-props

Can anyone tell me how I can bind the prop of a component to a data property of its own? For example, consider I have a component called `ModalComponent`

```
<template>  // ModalComponent.vue
   <div v-if="showModal">
      ...
      <button @click="showModal = !showModal">close the modal internally</button>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    show: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false,
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Now consider I am using this modal as a reusable component from inside a parent component using an external button to open up the pop up for the modal.

```
<template>
  <button @click="showChild = !showChild">click to open modal</button>
  <ModalComponent :show="showChild" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {ModalComponent},
  data() {
    return {
      showChild: false,    
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

How do I make it so that every time the parent clicks on the button, the modal pops up by binding the local `showModal` to the prop `show` ? And when the modal is closed internally by the local close button, if I click on the parent button again it will re-pop up? (I am using Vue 3, just in case)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: ModalComponent should emit an event instead of setting local showModal, that's a common approach for two-way binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The perfect solution for this case is using `v-model` instead of passing a prop :

in child component define `modelValue` as prop and emit its value to the parent using `$emit` function:

```
<template>  // ModalComponent.vue
   <div v-if="modelValue">
      ...
      <button @click="$emit('update:modelValue',!modelValue)">close the modal internally</button>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],

}
</script>
```

in parent component just use `v-model` to bind the value :

```
<template>
  <button @click="showChild = !showChild">click to open modal</button>
  <ModalComponent v-model="showChild" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {ModalComponent},
  data() {
    return {
      showChild: false,    
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#using-v-model-on-components